# LG G5 - Fingerprint Scanner gone

Tags: lg, fingerprint

I have an issue with the `LG G5`. I bought it like 3 weeks ago and used it very carefully. Now just while using the `fingerprint scanner` went away. it said restart the phone. After restart even the `option` is gone.

The same issue is reported here as well but no solution:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-g5/683019-fingerprint-options-missing.html

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have checked all forums for a way to fix my lg G5 fingerprint option that just dissapeared, i came across something, if you go into settings>general>lock screen>choose "none" exit and reset your phone once it starts up go back to settings>lock screen> and miraculously you should be able to activate your fingerprint option again

Comment: No miracle for me :-(. Still doesn't work.

Comment: When selecting none it warns saying finger print data will be deleted and will be insecure. Proceeded with that. After restarting I am able to set finger print again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how solved it:

`I returned the product and got my money back! This issue is for real as a lot of ppl have reported it`

The power button will soon stop working btw as its actually the whole fingerprint+power button that is low quality!

It only costs like 10 bucks on ebay but LG couldnt get a quality one!!

Answer (score 0):

Turn your phone off. Hold down the volume button then hold down the power button along with it until a bar code appears on your screen. Restart your phone and the fingerprint option should be back. Do it twice if it didn't work tge first time.

Comment: Tried this three or four times; didn't work for me.